# Cleaning GPS track data

Tags: data, gps, tracking, movement-data

I have data captured with a GPS tracking unit. Some track have bad/cold starts and the only way to determine the track quality is by using the altitude. Unfortunately I don't have the raw GPS data and only an array or Lat, Long & Altitude.

A typical bad start will have an altitude that start at negative with a steep ramp up to the proper altitude.

Is there any maths gurus and/or libraries (code) out there that can help me with an algorithm to detect and clean my track data?

Comment: Try GPSBabel. If you had raw data the filters would definitely do the job. GPSBabel reads CSV files, so see if you can format your array that way and use the filters. You can look at their code for ideas on gow to implement these.

Answer (score 2):

Hope Expert GPS will help you. Use the Simplify command to smooth out a tracklog that suffered from poor GPS reception.[image]

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but thanks for the info anyway.